# Microsoft Graph API - How to find out which user sent an email on behalf of a shared mailbox address with Send As permission?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I have a shared mailbox. The shared mailbox has an address SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com. A handful of users have access to send emails on behalf of that mailbox. Via the Microsoft Graph API, is it possible to see which user sent an individual email via the sharedbox1 address?

With this use case in mind, it makes sense this would only be something we would check on outgoing messages.

Looking at the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0 , the message properties specifically, is there any way to find which user sent an email on behalf of a shared mailbox?

For example, this is a (fake, all ids have been faked and sanitized) example email sent from a shared mailbox by a user on behalf of the shared mailbox represented in the the MS Graph API to 3 other users

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQSJDKJGKJGROwCC\"",
    "id": "AASDGSDGSDFMP4-RK_VSDFA1-bSDFSDFjB-JHUffy=",
    "createdDateTime": "2022-07-06T16:50:55Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2022-07-06T16:51:03Z",
    "changeKey": "CSDFSDFSDGSFDSDFSFCC",
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2022-07-06T16:50:00Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2022-07-06T16:50:45Z",
    "hasAttachments": false,
    "internetMessageId": "<PDSVSSVSVFGNFGHJ.something.prod.outlook.com>",
    "subject": "RE: Work Stuff",
    "importance": "normal",
    "parentFolderId": "SDFFGAGSDFHSDFHDFNIUERGHSJHDNVUIAGNOIGAIU",
    "conversationId": "JHFBVJHSBVJBVJHZVJ=",
    "conversationIndex": "ETHYTJTJDGNRYJD",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": false,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": true,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=SFBHWIUEwfADtegVAJBVSHFBVYUS&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "SHAREDBOX1",
            "address": "SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "SHAREDBOX1",
            "address": "SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com"
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Thad",
                "address": "thad@mycompany.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Chad",
                "address": "chad@mycustomer.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Vlad",
                "address": "vlad@mycustomer.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": [],
    "flag": {
        "flagStatus": "notFlagged"
    }
}
```

The email is from SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com, being sent to Chad, Vlad, and Thad.
Let's say the user who actually sent the email on behalf of SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com is brad@mycompany.com

I was hoping that the "sender" field would have contained brad@mycompany.com, as according to these docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#send-on-behalf but that appears to not be the case. Both "sender" and "from" are always populated as SHAREDBOX1@mycompany.com (so that would indicate that the permission on the shared box for the users is "Send As" instead of "Send on Behalf")https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user#send-as

Assuming the permission is "Send As", is there somewhere else in the API where that information can be looked up?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps Graph provides it, there is for sure a PowerShell script that can achieve this, whether or not Graph does is not something I'm going to search the internet for, but here's a link for the Powershell and perhaps it will help you find it in Graph: [audit-send-as-emails-in-microsoft-365-using-powershell](https://o365reports.com/2022/03/30/audit-send-as-emails-in-microsoft-365-using-powershell/)

Comment: Perhaps, right now we can only upvote this feature request in Graph API - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/determine-user-who-sent-a-shared-mailbox-message/idc-p/3766156#M1653